# Google Colab. Show time until next reset

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

does someone know if it is possible to show the time when the colab will reset the environment. I am currently using it for deep learning and I would like to know when the 12h of runtime is over without starting a timer myself.

Thanks!